# new custom Drupal 7 trigger to ban ip

Tags: triggers, drupal-7

I want to make a new custom system Drupal 7 trigger to ban the ip of a non-member who trues to access site content that does not exist and gets a "access denied"or "page not found"

The ban ip action is already available as a user action - but not for a dblog entry or attempts to access by non-authenticated (a.k.a non-member) users

I have looked at the custom trigger code available but i do not see (or know how to)  how to use it trigger on attempts to access non-existent nodes

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I found that there is a new module for that =>  https://www.drupal.org/project/tarpit - for Drupal 7